# List active connections with external servers in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

At times, emacs buffer talks to an external http (or) epc server and sends out queries. To do that, it establishes a network connection with it, which remains open until the query's response is written to process buffer. What command lists out the open connections between emacs & external server?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you are looking for. Does `M-x list-processes` show what you want to see?

Comment: yes, Chris... it serves my purpose.. thanks...